# Linux su password

Tags: linux, passwords, su

I want to change the user in one command line with su

```
echo password | su user
```

But this is not working. 
Is there a other possibility?
best wishes

Answer (score 3, accepted):

First of all: Ask yourself whether it is really necessary for a script to know the password. `sudo` and SE-Linux usually give you plenty of options to avoid entering passwords.

This being said, `su` opens its controlling terminal to read the password, not stdin. You can use `sudo` with the `-S` option to read the password from stdin.

Answer (score 1):

From `sudo`'s manual:

```
-S

The -S (stdin) option causes sudo to read the password from the standard input instead of the terminal device. The password must be followed by a newline character.
```

Answer (score 0):

Do the folowing ..

passwd root
it will ask you for a new password 
put it and then you log as administrator and do what you want